# Can I use a VS Code launch configuration to run Python without debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I understand that by creating a launch.json file in VS Code (slightly more cumbersome than pycharm), I can set debug configurations to launch individual python files.

For example:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        
        {
            "name": "Python: Poker",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "cwd": "C:/Users/dickr/git/poker",
            "program": "C:/Users/dickr/git/Poker/poker/main.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "env": {"PYTHONPATH": "${workspaceFolder}${pathSeparator}${env:PYTHONPATH}"}

        },
    ]
}
```

That all works great, but how can I run it in normal mode, without a debugger? How can this be defined in the launch configuration so I can select this in the dropdown, and potentially pass arguments with it?

Comment: or try **Run** | **Run without Debugging**

Comment: That’s not sufficient. I need it to be able to customise. Similar to what is available in pycharm. This seems a very basic and key feature that appears missing in vscode

Comment: construct a key board shortcut that types the command you want to the terminal: `python file.py arg1 arg2`

Comment: Ok so seems vscode is not mature enough to be used with python

Answer (score 0):

Just use a launch configuration as you would for debugging. Then use `Debug: Start Without Debugging` in the [command palette](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette), or use a keyboard shortcut. It's bound by default to <kbd>ctrl/cmd</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>. If you want to make a custom keyboard shortcut, its command ID is `workbench.action.debug.run`.

The VS Code Menu's "Run" menu should also have a "Run Without Debugging" item.

---

You could also write a task in a tasks.json file. For documentation on tasks, see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_custom-tasks.

Your might look something like this:

```json
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "label": "run python script",
      "type": "process",
      "command": "python3 C:/Users/dickr/git/Poker/poker/main.py",
      "options": {
        "cwd": "C:/Users/dickr/git/poker"
      },
      "presentation": {
        "reveal": "always",
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

though I'd suggest that if possible, you use [variable substitution](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks#_variable-substitution) to try to get rid of the absolute paths that won't be the same on other machines (assuming you want to be able to run the task on other machines).

Then run the task. You can even bind the task to keyboard shortcuts. See the documentation for more info: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/tasks.