# Can I use VS Code's launch config to just run a specific python file and not to debug it?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

In my Python project I have a module `my_stuff.py` which is active in my editor, but I want to execute the file `main.py` to run my project. -- Can I use `launch.json` for this?

I tried a simple config like this:

```json
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python: Main File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "main.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal",
            "justMyCode": true
        },
    ]
}
```

But this always wants to start the `debugpy` launcher. I would just like to launch the main file as

```bash
/my/venv/python /my/project/dir/main.py
```

How can I do this with `launch.json`?

Comment: [Run --> Run Without Debugging](https://imgur.com/VSWybt4.png)?

Comment: duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/68262943/11107541

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now you can configure [`program`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging#_program) in *launch.json* and then use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> (`Run Without Debugging`)to execute the program. *But essentially this still uses the debugger*.

[image]

There was a feature request to configure the **Run** button, but it was closed due to insufficient votes.

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/20269

There is also a related request open.

- https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/11812

There is also a related SO question.

- [How can I configure the "Run" button next to the editor tabs in VS Code for Python files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75547380/how-can-i-configure-the-run-button-next-to-the-editor-tabs-in-vs-code-for-pyth)